# How to identify a word(case insensitive) using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in java `Select * from tbl_Name tn where tn.PublicID='?'`and I am trying to find the occurrence of `.PublicID='?'` considering case insensitivity.

I am using below regex expression `(?i).PublicID[ ]?=\'\?\'`, but it is not able to find any match in above string

Java Snippet used

```
String query = "";
                    if(queryOrTable.equalsIgnoreCase("Query"))
                    {
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i).PublicID[ ]?=\\'\\?\\'");

                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tblName);
                        if(matcher.matches())
                        {
                            query = query.replaceAll("(?i).PublicID[ ]?=\\'\\?\\'", ".PublicID='" + publicID + "'");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("malformed query");
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: And are you using it with `matches()` or `find()`? Show the code.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to find your matches?

Comment: The pattern matches Try using a double escape for the backslash `(?i)\\.PublicID[ ]?='\\?'` Also escape the dot to match it literally.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added the code I used

Comment: You have `matches`. Do not use it. Use `find` if you must check for a match before replacing. Or, replace and compare old and new strings.

Answer (score -1):

That should work.

Tested here: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Now, instead of `[ ]?` matching one space, I'd use `\s*`.

You are matching one optional space with yours, I'm saying match 0 or more whitespace characters (which will work for more cases of SQL than what you're looking for.